# Create Outlook add-in using Angular

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, angular7

I'm trying to create an Outlook add-in using Angular 7 that can access all the users in my organization with Microsoft Graph API. In order to do that, I need to authenticate the current user and get an access token for calling graph API. I am planning to do the authentication using Single Sign On (SSO).

I read the documentation and didn't find any solution to my problem. My current add-in doesn't have a back-end, just a front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work with Office add-ins in Preview right now and requires you to have a server side component and an Azure AD registered application. There are detailed steps on accomplishing that here for asp.net and nodejs. There is no examples with Angular though unfortunately:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins